# How to parse text data from a binary file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, binary

Hi I have a binary file that contains lots of resources and using C# I want to find and parse the text objects in this file that are in ASCII like below

Lots of binary junk before

ONMAP 0 131072 "description " 0 "name" "FLAG" "FLAG" 7900.000000 0.000000 1499.999268 2.000000 6.000000 8.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0 -1 0.101900 2 36 255
followed by a line break

lots of binary junk after these objects

Each object begins with its tag ONMAP here, the values are separated by white space and the strings double quoted and must be read in the order they were written, we don’t know where the data is in the file so I want to search through the binary until that onmap is found and read the properties  into a List but once found that onmap i dont know how to parse the properties in.

Comment: If you store binary data, why don't you store binary-serialized object? Then deserialize it and use properties? Why making life hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend locating the beginning of the string by getting the format of the file which will contain points to the beginning of the string.  The code below will work under most situations, but is not guaranteed.  Gnu utilities basically does the same.  Utilities like this should only be used as quick solutions.  Binary data is pseudo random and it is possible that a 5 character match is possible, but very remote.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            FIND_ONMAP,
            FIND_RETURN,
            DONE
        }

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<byte> onmap = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ONMAP").ToList();

            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FILENAME);
            int data = 0;
            State state = State.FIND_ONMAP;
            List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
            while ((data = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case State.FIND_ONMAP:
                        if (buffer.Count < 5)
                        {
                            buffer.Add((byte)(data & 0xff));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer.RemoveAt(0);
                            buffer.Add((byte)(data & 0xff));
                        }
                        if (buffer.SequenceEqual(onmap))
                        {
                            state = State.FIND_RETURN;
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.FIND_RETURN:
                        if (data == 10)
                        {
                            state = State.DONE;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer.Add((byte)(data & 0xff));
                        }
                        break;

                }
                if (state == State.DONE) break;

            }


            if (state == State.DONE)
            {
                string results = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(results);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a standard Unix program that does exactly what you're looking for: [strings](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23/binutils/strings.html).

You can find the source under Gnu binutils:

http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

The program is small and relatively simple.  The "algorithms" it uses are directly applicable to C# (or, equivalently, to Java or C++).